# categorize browser JavaScript API's

Tags: javascript, api, browser

in the web browser there is available lots of JavaScript web API's
all of those are listed in here(Firefox browser web API list page)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API

in here list is going very long....
are these API's not categorized in any where?

if then we can  identify which feature are available in web browser easily among those big long list of API's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/). It's a script that detects a definable selection of HTML5/CSS3 features in the browser, and then exposes them both to [CSS via classes on the HTML element](https://modernizr.com/docs/#using-modernizr-with-css) and [Javascript via the `Modernizr` object](https://modernizr.com/docs/#using-modernizr-with-javascript). It also has an [interactive API](https://modernizr.com/docs/#modernizr-api).

The list of supported features is at the bottom of the help page, and follow logical categorization as you require.

Comment: why browser developers not provide such a list for supported API's

Comment: and also this list contains not only JavaScript feature css  technologies  also

Answer (score 1):

It's very difficult to make a full, up-to-date list of all the APIs since it varies a lot (most notably, some new features are only partially available in some versions of modern browsers).

As a rule-of-thumb - everything that is ES3 is OK to use everywhere. Everything that is ES5 *should* be OK, but some older browsers (IE8, most notably) don't support it. Everything that is ES6 and beyond is *mostly* not supported out of the box (there are some libraries and special tools that allow you to use some of these features, though).

Finally, here are some good sites to help you with this:

- [Can I use...](http://caniuse.com/) which contains detailed information about every API.
- [ES5 compatbility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/)
- [ES6 compatbility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)
- [ES7 compatbility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es7/)
- [Non-standard features compatbility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/non-standard/)

Answer (score 0):

all the api's are listed  in here
in here all the objects of api's are categorized in under the api names
http://www.w3.org/standards/techs/js#stds